# aggregated counter based on the condition

Tags: pandas

Existing Dataframe :

```
Id      action_date         diff_of_time_in_sec          
A        2021-06-09                 10                          
A        2021-06-09                 200                         
A        2021-06-09                 1300                        
A        2021-06-09                 1500                        
B        2021-06-10                  2                          
B        2021-06-10                  15                         
B        2021-06-10                  100                        
B        2021-06-10                  2000
```

Expected Dataframe :

```
Id      action_date         diff_of_time_in_sec          session_counter
A        2021-06-09                 10                          1
A        2021-06-09                 200                         1
A        2021-06-09                 1300                        2
A        2021-06-09                 1500                        3
B        2021-06-10                  2                          1
B        2021-06-10                  15                         1
B        2021-06-10                  100                        1
B        2021-06-10                  2000                       2
```

I am trying to create a session counter based on diff_of_time_in_sec column.
wherever the **diff_of_time_in_sec** is **greater than 1200** , a new session has to start

this is what i have tried :

```
df['Session_Conter'] = ((df['diff_of_time_in_sec'] > 1200)
                                 .groupby(df['Id']).cumsum())
```

Comment: why you counted 200 (row 2), when the value is below 1200?

Comment: The logic is unclear, do you want to restart the counter every 1200 seconds?

Comment: @mozway i am trying to find the number of sessions based on time_difference.  if time difference is more than 1200 it states that the new session is started. counter should be incremental for that Id

Comment: Why is the last row of A having a counter of 3? it is not above 2400s. How do you define the time difference? Successive or from 0?

Answer (score 0):

The logic is unclear.

If you want to have a counter every 1200 seconds, no need for a groupby:

```
df['session_counter'] = df['diff_of_time_in_sec'].floordiv(1200).add(1)
```

output:

```
  Id action_date  diff_of_time_in_sec  session_counter
0  A  2021-06-09                   10                1
1  A  2021-06-09                  200                1
2  A  2021-06-09                 1300                2
3  A  2021-06-09                 1500                2
4  B  2021-06-10                    2                1
5  B  2021-06-10                   15                1
6  B  2021-06-10                  100                1
7  B  2021-06-10                 2000                2
```

Comment: for the row no. 3 , it should count it as new session , i.e. counter should show 3 .  basically i was having a date with timestamp. this diff of time is created using that. generally any session lasts for 1200 sec. so i was looking for incremental counter

Comment: @Roshankumar it's still unclear, if there was a fifth A row with 1501, would the number be 4? Would `df['diff_of_time_in_sec'].gt(1200).groupby(df['Id']).cumsum().add(1)` work for you?

Answer (score 0):

```
def function1(dd:pd.DataFrame):
    dd['col1']=(dd.diff_of_time_in_sec>1200).cumsum()+1
    return dd

df1.groupby('Id').apply(function1)

  Id action_date  diff_of_time_in_sec  col1
0  A  2021-06-09                   10     1
1  A  2021-06-09                  200     1
2  A  2021-06-09                 1300     2
3  A  2021-06-09                 1500     3
4  B  2021-06-10                    2     1
5  B  2021-06-10                   15     1
6  B  2021-06-10                  100     1
7  B  2021-06-10                 2000     2
```